# How to get number of reply in a forum

Tags: api, rss, forum

Does any one have an idea how I could get the number of views and reply from a topic via an API ? I'm looking to make stats from a SMF forum post. The RSS feed allows only to follow a forum and not a topic. There are tools or PHP commands to extract the data ?

Comment: For number of replies, I would probably check the link on each post in the feed (It will be something like `http://forums.somesite.example/index.php/topic,7052.msg196426.html#msg196426`), and see if the topic value matches.  I could count that.  Though that feels like the wrong way to do this, and it certainly can't get the views that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution some of our customers come up with:

- Use the feeds as a discovery mechanism for new posts/new messages. Basically, you subscribe to the "main" feed of the forum to get all new threads, then, for each thread, subscribe to its specific feed to get all new posts in the thread. For each notification, just keep track of the URL.
- Then, they use our [fragment subscription](http://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html#htmlfragments) feature, where they can subscribe to a specific element in the DOM of the page. In your case, you would subscribe to the the element that inclde the number of reads or replies to a given post (or thread).

This way, they can just have a 'listener' application that registers webhooks. These webhooks are triggered when there are new posts and new reads or replies.